# Can I use strings as comments in c++?

Tags: python, c++, string, comments

In Python, there are two types of comments.
The first using `#` (One-line comments)

```py
# This is a comment
This_is_not()
```

The other using `"""`/`'''` (Multi-line comments)

```py
"""
This is a comment
"""
'''
Yet another comment
'''
NOT_a_comment()
```

---

In C++, there are two types of comments.
The first using `//` (One-line comments)

```cpp
// This is a comment
This_is_not_a_comment();
```

The other using `/*`/`*/` (Multi-line comments)

```cpp
/*
This is a comment
*/
This_is____well_you_get_the_idea();
```

---

My question is,
**Can I use strings as comments in C++?**
If I do, `gcc` gives me a warning.

```
warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
    "This is a comment";
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But if I just ignore the warning (With `-Wno-unused-value` possibly) It will be okay, right?

Comment: *technically* they aren't comments in Python either. They are string literals.

Comment: It is because of the difference in the syntax of making comment is `C++` and `python`

Comment: why sould """...""" be _comments_? They are f.e. used as documenting strings - and if placed anywhere else they are simply strings that are created and destroyed  becausse no instance is referencing them ...

Comment: The premise of the question is flawed. Python multi-line string literals (`"""..."""`) aren't comments.

Comment: Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) says, "A comment starts with a hash character (#) that is not part of a string literal, and ends at the end of the physical line." There is no other comment syntax in Python.

Comment: @molbdino You are right, they aren't comments. But a lot people use them as if they are, and my question is if C++ can accept strings if they are in place of comments

Comment: @molbdilno Sorry, wrong name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments are skipped by the compilers during compilation whereas values and their assignments aren't. It'll be better to avoid using unused string values because nevertheless they're unused, they're at least included in compilation. OTOH, comments are ignored.